# C++ reading from .txt file

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have a strange problem that seems to happen when I pass an ifstream by reference.

In my main method, I have created an ifstream, and then I pass it to this read method by reference:

```
    void ArrayStorage::read(ifstream& fin)
{
    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        string input;
        getline(fin, input, '\n');
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

This should work fine, however, I'm getting the following message in the value of the ifstream:

> - fin {_Filebuffer={_Set_eback=0xcccccccc  _Set_egptr=0xcccccccc  ...} }   std::basic_ifstream > &

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Code that calls the method:

```
ifstream fin1("data.txt");
ofstream out1("1-In-SortedRead.txt");

if(!fin1.is_open()) 
{
    cout << "FAIL" << endl;
    return 1;
}

ArrayStorage arrayStorage1;

// read in values into data structure
arrayStorage1.read(fin1);
```

Comment: That's not a message. I's a dump of implementation state. Does the code work?

Comment: What do you mean "value of the ifstream"?

Comment: Sorry, probably should have made that clearer; this is what Intellisense shows as in the "Value" in the variable watch at a breakpoint. The code does not work.

Comment: Have added the code that creates the stream, and calls the method

Comment: Are you running this under *Release*? Because debugging in release tends to give you that sort of behaviour. What about the result of the program itself?

Comment: The debugging information is talking about the pointer positions for the underlying streambuf.  eback is the beginning of the memory for reading, egptr is the end of the memory for reading.  Pretty sure your file is empty, or you're getting the wrong file or something like that.

Comment: Add `std::cout << input << "\n"` after `std::getline`.

Comment: How do you know the code does not work? It reads line and throws it away. If you are running optimized code instead of debug build, for example the whole `input` variable might have gotten optimized out of the code. You can't reliably look at release build behaviour under debugger, assembly code which is running under debugger may not resemble the C++ source code very much any more...